# C++ Ordered Linked List Search Function Algorithm logic

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, linked-list

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to write an algorithm to search a linked list, but I'm having a little trouble with my logic. The ??? question marks in bold are the parts I'm having trouble with. I appreciate any help with this.

```
  ListNode *MyLinkedList::Search(int key)
{
    ListNode *temp = head;  // Assume ListNode is a structure and contains the variable int key;
    // Search for the key
    while((temp != NULL) && (key != temp->key))
    {
        temp = temp -> next; // Advance to next node
    {
    if(**???**)     // Make sure node is found
    {   
        return **???**; // If found, return appropriate value
    }
    else 
    {   
        return NULL;  // return NULL when not found
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless this is homework (or something similar) you should probably use `std::list` and `std::find`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [searching in linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840420/searching-in-linked-list)

Comment: Thanks to all for the help, my confusion is cleared up now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key was found `key == temp->key` will be true and `temp != NULL` will be false, so:

```
if(key == temp->key)     // Make sure node is found
{   
    return temp; // If found, return appropriate value
}
```

OR:

```
if (temp != NULL)     // Make sure node is found
{   
    return temp; // If found, return appropriate value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
ListNode *MyLinkedList::Search(int key, ListNode *head)
{
    ListNode *temp = head;  // Assume ListNode is a structure and contains the variable         int key;
    // Search for the key
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if (key == temp->key)
           return temp;
        temp = temp -> next; // Advance to next node
    }
    return NULL;  // return NULL when not found
}
```

**EDIT**

You should use the list from stl and the find algorithm, if you aren't required to write your own container; They are tested and safe:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `if`. Just return `temp`. If the correct key is present in the list, `temp` would be pointing to it, otherwise it's `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
if(temp != NULL) // Make sure node is found
{
    return temp; // Make sure node is found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if(temp != NULL)     // Make sure node is found
{   
    return temp; // If found, return appropriate value
}
```

But much simpler is just

```
return temp;
```

since if temp is null, you want to return null anyway.